# Can low ink lead to paper not moving and so no blank photocopy?

Tags: hp-deskjet

For HP 2132 printer, the ink is low as not used much after buying around 3 years back. Took around 5 pages printout just after buying and then packed.

Yesterday, I thought to check the condition of the printer. While using HP Smart App, the printer easily connected with Windows laptop, and could scan properly (cannot print as showing low ink).

I tried to take photocopy but paper remaining still and so unable to take even blank printouts. I would like to confirm if it is low ink that is preventing from paper moving?

[Screenshots](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFWapM9Uqo/Qo_sp7sOeNImG5jYoE0TMg/watch?utm_content=DAFWapM9Uqo&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link&utm_source=publishsharelink)

Comment: Have you checked what the printer thinks the ink condition is? After three years, I'd expect 'dried up solid', which the printer may not be able to accurately evaluate.

Comment: Yes, getting message of low ink once connected with HP Smart app. Able to scan properly. My query is using this printer for photocopy (without connecting with computer), even if I intend to take a blank printout, I am not getting. The pages are not rolling. Could it be due to low ink as well?

Comment: It can't photocopy if it has no ink. What do you consider a "blank printout"?? The machine doesn't know if you put a blank sheet in to scan.

Comment: I mean I expect the paper to roll from tray to giving an output (even if it is blank). The paper not rolling. So is there any technical issue with the printer?

Comment: Why would you expect that? If it has no ink it cannot print, so it won't feed paper.

Comment: Okay, this was my query. The paper will not feed if printer ink low/dried. So once I replace the cartridge, hopefully it will feed.

Comment: Be prepared to spend a day soaking the heads in warm water too ;))

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the machine is out of ink [or even just thinks it is] then it will not perform any operation that it would expect to use ink in.

That would include photocopying a blank sheet of paper. It has no way of knowing that your sheet will actually require no ink.

After three years of no usage, the ink & heads will likely be dried solid. Check the manufacturer's manual for how to deal with this. It will likely require a long soak to soften the ink dried into the heads. It may, in fact, never quite clear itself properly.